# Converting and comparing DateTime which are in different formats

Tags: javascript, datetime

Currently I have an app that's making a rest call to the SharePoint api that gives me the last modified date, and then I am comparing that date to a date that I currently have stored as a tag in content control inside a word doc.  Currently I am using the `New Date()` method to try and compare the two dates, however I am getting two different times.  Both these date times are in UTC but formatted different.

The DateTime that I am getting from SharePoint is in this format: `2016-08-27T17:40:09Z`

The DateTime stored in a Content Controls tag: `8/27/2016 5:40:09 PM`

**Current Code:**

```
 for (var x = 0; x < contentControls.items.length; x++) {
                        itemUrl = "https://*tenant*.sharepoint.com/sites/*site*/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('*list*')/items?select=Title,Title&$filter=Title eq '" + contentControls.items[x].title + "'";
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            async: false,
                            url: itemUrl,
                            headers: {
                                "Authorization": "Bearer " + sharepointToken,
                                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                            },
                            success: function (data) {

                                var sharepointDateTime = data.d.results[0].Modified;
                                var contentControlDateTime = contentControls.items[0].tag;

                                var test1 = new Date(sharepointDateTime);
                                var test2 = new Date(contentControlDateTime);

                                if (test1 != test2) {
                                    // custom code
                                }                                    
                            },
                            error: function (error) {
                                console.log("Fetching list from SharePoint failed.");
                            }
                        })
                    }
```

**Desired Result**

I would like to be able to compare two dates in my condition statement, and if they are different I am going I am going to do something inside my statement.  **VERY Important**  this can not be dependent on the users current time Zone.  I am comparing **UTC Time**

**Update**

I have solved this by altering the api which is stamping the content controls. I am working in a time crunch so I could not really dwell much on this. What I saw was that the content control tags were not stamped with the time zone so it was comparing apples and oranges. However, I would like to leave this question open to see if some one can find a client side solution instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing object references of two date objects with each other using `!=`, not points of time. While the objects may represent the same point of time, the condition will always be true.

Instead you could compare the timestamps of the two dates as number values, which you can retrieve using [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf):

```
test1.valueOf() != test2.valueOf()
```

---

Also note that the second date does not contain any time zone information, so it [will be interpreted in the local time zone of the environment the code is executed in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Differences_in_assumed_time_zone). This may lead to unexpected results.

You may want to [look into Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/), which is the de-facto standard library for date handling in JavaScript and which offers a [much more consistent and intuitive API](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/js-date/) for your use case.

Comment: Hey Tim, .value() gives me an epoch timestamp, which I can compare as well.  I have solved this by altering the api which is stamping the content controls.  I am working in a time crunch so I could not really dwell much on this.  What I saw the content control tags were not stamped with the time zone so it was comparing apples and oranges.  However, I would like to leave this question open to see if some one can find a client side solution instead. Thank you.